# Isomorphism between a power set $\{0, 1\}^n$ (regarded as a ring) and n digit binary number?

Tags: ring-theory

We can treat a power set of a set as ring, $A+B = A\cup B-A\cap B, A\times B = A\cap B$.

Can we use 'modified' modular binary additions and multiplications to represent addition and multiplication of a power set of finite set $X$.

I try this way: say $X=\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$, a subset containing $a_1, a_2$ will be represented by $1100...00$, other subsets will be represented similarly: if $a_i$ is in the subset, then $i$th digit will be $1$.

Then $\{a_2\}+\{a_2\}=\{\}$ while $010...0+010...0=100...0 _{n \ digits}\mod 1000...0 _{n+1 \ digits}$ which represents $\{a_1\}$.

It doesn't work.

But is there any way to make it work, i.e. is there a one one correspondence of a power set of n elements and an n-digit binary number which is also an isomorphism w.r.t. multiplication and addition?

Comment: Just for the binary numbers: are the addition and multiplication the built-in addition and multiplication of the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t really understand, what you mean by *modified modular binary additions and multiplications*. For bitwise operation we get an isomorphism.

Let $X$ be a fixed set. We have the powerset ring $P=(\mathcal{P}(X),\Delta,\cap,\emptyset,X)$ as well as the ring of binary representations $B=\prod\limits_X \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. We can define a map
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
P &\rightarrow &B\\
A & \mapsto & (\delta_{x,A})_x
\end{array}$$,
where
$$\delta_{x,A}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}1&\text{if }x\in A\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

It is not hard to see that this map is a bijection of the underlying sets. It clearly maps $\emptyset$ to $(0)_x$ and $X$ to $(1)_x$. So we are left to show that it respects addition and multiplication. For $A,B\in P$ it suffices to note that for $x\in X$ the identities (in $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ of cause)
$$\delta_{x,A\Delta B} = \delta_{x,A} + \delta_{x,B}$$
and
$$\delta_{x,A\cap B} = \delta_{x,A}\delta_{x,B}$$
hold. So we have defined an isomorphism of rings $P \cong B$.

Comment: I see. The  $(\delta_{x,A})_x$ is comparison of A and X element by element (of X). And we can define the bitwise addition also digit by digit, e.g. 010+010=000. The only difference is simply that here we don’t do carry of digit.

Comment: And bitwise multiplication is just defined as, for example, 010 AND 010, i.e. AND logic digit by digit, which is completely different from usual binary multiplication,e.g. 0010*0100=1000

Comment: Exactly. This is **not** addition and multiplication in the sense of binary representation of integer numbers (with carrying etc), but bitwise addition and multiplication (considering bits independent of each other)